# Como modificar el Path de Sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

No puedo cambiar el `path` de `SQLITE`.

Programo una base de datos en `android studio` y la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Tengo:

```
public Constructor (Context ctx){
        super(ctx, NombreBase, null, 1)
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("create table miTabla (ID integer ,Nombre text)");
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que me guarda la base de datos en:

```
data/data/miproyecto/NombreBase.db
```

Y yo quiero por ejemplo que la guarde en:

```
data/data/otronombre/NombreBase.db
```

O sea la pregunta es como modifico la ubicación para que cambie el `path`?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el constructor debes de pasar el path donde quieres guardar la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 MyDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/NombreBase.db", null, 1);
 }
}
```

Debes de asegurarte que tu aplicación tiene los permisos necesario para poder guardar archivos en el almacenamiento externo.

Por seguridad no es recomendable guardar la base de datos en un path externo al de tu app.

Comenta si te ha servido!

Comment: Te explico creo la base de datos y funciona todo bien. Pero cuando quiero cambiar la ruta como vos me explicas se detiene el programa, Igualmente tengo los permisos de root.

Comment: Los permisos de root no tienen nada te ver, me refiero a los permisos del archivo manifest de la aplicación, te recomiendo leer este enlace: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html específicamente en el apartado de permisos, para guardar archivos en el almacenamiento externo necesitas utilizar este permiso:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: No siempre va a ser "/mnt/sdcard/", es diferente dependiendo del dispositivo.

Comment: @Jorgesys, es solo por ilustrar un ejemplo, por su puesto dependiendo de las necesidades de cada uno se puede modificar el path